# Static lib in c++ not working

Tags: c++, makefile

I have folder `ClientServer`.
In this folder I have two other folders, `Database` and `Server`.
In `Server` folder I have classes that use "database.h" and "newsgroup.h". 
These files are in `Database` folder. I created a lib with this make file. I moved the libfile to `ClientServer` folder. Then I try to call Make in `Server` folder; I get error.

```
Makefile:47: ans.d: No such file or directory
Makefile:47: com.d: No such file or directory
Makefile:47: myserver.d: No such file or directory
In file included from myserver.cc:11:0:
ans.h:4:23: fatal error: newsGroup.h: No such file or directory

#include "newsGroup.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.


#
# Makefile to make the file libclientserver.a, containing
# connection.o and server.o
#
# Define the compiler. g++ can be
# changed to clang++.
CXX = g++
CC  = g++

# Define preprocessor, compiler, and linker flags. Uncomment the # lines
# if you use clang++ and wish to use libc++ instead of libstdc++.
CXXFLAGS =  -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wold-style-cast 
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 
#CPPFLAGS =  -stdlib=libc++
#CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#LDFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++

all: libdatabase.a

# Create the library; ranlib is for Darwin and maybe other systems.
# Doesn't seem to do any damage on other systems.

libdatabase.a: Database.o newsGroup.o
    ar rv libdatabase.a Database.o newsGroup.o 
    ranlib libdatabase.a

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all clean

# Standard clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o libclientserver.a

# Generate dependencies in *.d files
%.d: %.cc
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CPP) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$

# Include the *.d files
SRC = $(wildcard *.cc)
include $(SRC:.cc=.d)
```

Comment: Your dependency handling is overcomplicated and not quite correct. Try `-include $(SRC:.cc=.d)`

Comment: That means it can't find the header file, not the lib.

Comment: why does it need the header file then everything should be in the lib.

Comment: You always need a header file, is the interface of your library. You library just contains the implementation (in the best of cases), your headers contain the function calls. When there is no header file, headaches and crying of blood ensues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `newsGroup.h` placed in your directory structure? Do the `.cpp` files see it in the same directory?? Otherwise use the `-I` option, to tell the compiler in which directory this file can be found.

Add e.g. `-I <path_to>/Database` to your `CXXFLAGS`, where `<path_to>` might be either a full, or relative path to the working directory used to run the compiler:

```
CXXFLAGS += -I<path_to>/Database
```

Another option is to specify a relative path in the `#include` statements, e.g. in `ans.h` write

```
#include "Database/newsGroup.h"
```

and have the `-I` option just point to `<path_to>/`.
Since the `.d` files will receive these paths when generated and specify the dependencies at that point should also see the `.h` dependencies relative from `make`'s working directory.

Comment: newsGroup is in Database folder
ans class is in Server folder.
THese two folders are in ClientServer folder.

Comment: @user2975699 So you'll need to add something like `-I <path_to>/Database` to your `CXXFLAGS`, where `<path_to>`might be either a full or relative path to the working directory used to run the compiler.

Comment: CPPFLAGS  = -I..
I have another libfile that is in Clintserver folder and that one is working.

Comment: CPPFLAGS  = -I..
CXXFLAGS =  -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wold-style-cast 
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS =   -g -L..
#CPPFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#LDFLAGS +=  -stdlib=libc++

# Libraries
LDLIBS =lclientsever -ldatabase

Comment: I added two path
now I get /Desktop/ClientServer/Server$ make: *** No rule to make target `newsGroup.h', needed by `myserver.d'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a library just holds "the body of the functions".

You still have to declare the prototypes of functions (include `.h` files), and make it accessible for the compiler.

So, in your case, make `newsgroup.h` accessible to your compiler (in this case, put it in the same folder as the `ans.h` file), it should resolve the problem.